# Why does the replace function in Pandas elicit a SettingWithCopyWarning?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to replace values in a particular column of a data frame. I tried several methods but they either do not work or they elicit a SettingWithCopyWarning. I would like to understand what the proper way would be. I found some older questions but I think they are based on an outdated syntax and do not reflect the current 'good practice'.

At first I tried

```
df.loc[:,['UNDERINFL']].replace(['N','Y'],['0', '1'], inplace = True)
```

This does not elicit any error or warning but it also does not replace anything.

Then I tried

```
df.loc[:,['UNDERINFL']] = df.loc[:,['UNDERINFL']].replace(['N','Y'],['0', '1'])
```

This works but it also throws the SettingWithCopyWarning and encourages me to use .loc = value, which I thought I am doing.

Can someone tell me the proper way to do this?

Comment: `df['UNDERINFL'] = df['UNDERINFL'].replace(['N','Y'],['0', '1'])`

Comment: This works as well but it also throws the same warning. Could it just be a Jupyter Notebook issue?

Comment: That's because your `df` seems to be a part of an event bigger dataframe. How did you define your `df`?

Comment: Good call! Before I wanted to replace the values, I attempted to remove all the rows where this particular column had no values with `df = df[df.loc[:,'UNDERINFL'].notnull()]`. I guess this must have replaced `df` with a view of itself. Using `df = df[df.loc[:,'UNDERINFL'].notnull()].copy()` makes the following 'replace' line run without any warning.